# Passing a Set of Objects between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, events

The current project I am working on requires that I implement a way to efficiently pass a set of objects from one thread, that runs continuously, to the main thread. The current setup is something like the following.

I have a main thread which creates a new thread. This new thread operates continuously and calls a method based on a timer. This method fetches a group of messages from an online source and organizes them in a TreeSet.

This TreeSet then needs to be passed back to the main thread so that the messages it contains can be handled independent of the recurring timer.

For better reference my code looks like the following

```
// Called by the main thread on start.  
void StartProcesses()
{
    if(this.IsWindowing)
    {
        return;
    }

    this._windowTimer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            WindowCallback();
        }
    };

    this.CancellationToken = false; 
    _windowTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,
            0, this.SQSWindow, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    this.IsWindowing = true;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

private void WindowCallback()
{
    ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    //TODO create Monitor
    if((!CancellationToken))
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO fix epochWindowTime
            long epochWindowTime = 0;
            int numberOfMessages = 0;
            Map<String, String> attributes;

            // Setup the SQS client
            AmazonSQS client = new AmazonSQSClient(new 
                    ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());

            client.setEndpoint(this.AWSSQSServiceUrl);

            // get the NumberOfMessages to optimize how to 
            // Receive all of the messages from the queue

            GetQueueAttributesRequest attributesRequest = 
                    new GetQueueAttributesRequest();
            attributesRequest.setQueueUrl(this.QueueUrl);
            attributesRequest.withAttributeNames(
                    "ApproximateNumberOfMessages");
            attributes = client.getQueueAttributes(attributesRequest).
                    getAttributes();

            numberOfMessages = Integer.valueOf(attributes.get(
                    "ApproximateNumberOfMessages")).intValue();

            // determine if we need to Receive messages from the Queue
            if (numberOfMessages > 0)
            {

                if (numberOfMessages < 10)
                {
                    // just do it inline it's less expensive than 
                    //spinning threads
                    ReceiveTask(numberOfMessages);
                }
                else
                {
                    //TODO Create a multithreading version for this
                    ReceiveTask(numberOfMessages);
                }
            }

            if (!CancellationToken)
            {

                //TODO testing
                _setLock.lock();

                Iterator<Message> _setIter = _set.iterator();
                //TODO
                while(_setIter.hasNext())
                {
                    Message temp = _setIter.next();

                    Long value = Long.valueOf(temp.getAttributes().
                            get("Timestamp"));
                    if(value.longValue() < epochWindowTime)
                    {
                        messages.add(temp);
                        _set.remove(temp);
                    }
                }

                _setLock.unlock();

                // TODO deduplicate the messages

                // TODO reorder the messages

                // TODO raise new Event with the results
            }

            if ((!CancellationToken) && (messages.size() > 0))
            {
                if (messages.size() < 10)
                {
                    Pair<Integer, Integer> range = 
                            new Pair<Integer, Integer>(Integer.valueOf(0), 
                                    Integer.valueOf(messages.size()));
                    DeleteTask(messages, range);
                }
                else
                {
                    //TODO Create a way to divide this work among 
                    //several threads
                    Pair<Integer, Integer> range = 
                            new Pair<Integer, Integer>(Integer.valueOf(0), 
                                    Integer.valueOf(messages.size()));
                    DeleteTask(messages, range);
                }
            }
        }catch (AmazonServiceException ase){
            ase.printStackTrace();
        }catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            ace.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen by some of the commenting, my current preferred way to handle this is by creating an event in the timer thread if there are messages. The main thread will then be listening for this event and handle it appropriately.

Presently I am unfamiliar with how Java handles events, or how to create/listen for them. I also do not know if it is possible to create events and have the information contained within them passed between threads.

Can someone please give me some advice/insight on whether or not my methods are possible? If so, where might I find some information on how to implement them as my current searching attempts are not proving fruitful.

If not, can I get some suggestions on how I would go about this, keeping in mind I would like to avoid having to manage sockets if at all possible.

**EDIT 1:**

The main thread will also be responsible for issuing commands based on the messages it receives, or issuing commands to get required information. For this reason the main thread cannot wait on receiving messages, and should handle them in an event based manner.

Answer (score 1):

Producer-Consumer Pattern:

One thread(producer) continuosly stacks objects(messages) in a queue.
another thread(consumer) reads and removes objects from the queue.

If your problem fits to this, Try "BlockingQueue".
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

It is easy and effective.

If the queue is empty, consumer will be "block"ed, which means the thread waits(so do not uses cpu time) until producer puts some objects. otherwise cosumer continuosly consumes objects.
And if the queue is full, prducer will be blocked until consumer consumes some objects to make a room in the queue, vice versa.

Here's a example:
(a queue should be same object in both producer and consumer)

---

(Producer thread)

```
Message message = createMessage();
queue.put(message);
```

(Consumer thread)

```
Message message = queue.take();
handleMessage(message);
```

Comment: Unfortunately a BlockingQueue won't work, the main thread that is consuming the messages must also be able to generate commands to the service among other things.

Comment: Isn't that just asking for two queues? Message passing in languages like Erlang and Scala's Actor model have a mailbox/message queue per thread.

Comment: Its not as simple as creating two queues, the main thread does not send any information to the "message gathering" thread, and only receives information from it after it has been started. The main thread then creates http connections to external services, that may or may not generate messages for the "message gathering" thread to collect.