# Using Events to pass information between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, events

Is it possible to use events and event listeners to pass a set of information between two threads in Java? If I simplify my problem to its base, I have a producer and consumer with each one "living" on its own thread. The producer creates messages, and once a message is created it "idealy" would send an event to the consumer. The consumer will be doing many things, but will also be listening for a producer event. This means that the consumer can not be blocked or wait for the producer.

If this is possible, where could I find a generic example to work from?

For more information on the model please see

[Passing a Set of Objects between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144317/passing-a-set-of-objects-between-threads)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass some message from One Thread to another On a specific event, 
 you should have a third Static class that should have these Threads running,

1. One thread Send Information in a List which resides in static class
   while 
    
   Other
2. Thread is reading from that Static Clas's List, if
       there exist some data sends by first thread, this thread will
       perform some operation according to that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use events and event listeners to pass a set of information between two threads in Java?

Yes.

> If I simplify my problem to its base, I have a producer and consumer with each one "living" on its own thread. The producer creates messages, and once a message is created it "idealy" would send an event to the consumer.

Events and event listeners are more complicated than what you need to solve this problem.

What you need is a message queue.

Java provides the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) implementation of an AbstractQueue.  Your producer thread adds messages to the queue, and your consumer thread takes messages (polls) from the queue.

If your consumer thread finds nothing on the queue, it goes to sleep for X milliseconds, then checks the queue again.

If you decide you still want to use events and event listeners, read this informative article, [Event Listener](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=150).  You'll have to make the `List`s that store the event listeners thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

> "The consumer will be doing many things, but will also be listening
>   for a producer event".

Just unify all job execution by the consumer thread - put all that "things" in the input queue of the consumer, so the consumer would block only when there is really nothing to do.